# Print the error message returned from the SQL query

Tags: 7, database

I created a custom module where I am querying the database, for example with code similar to the following one.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid'));
$nid = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

I want to print the warning, error, and success messages after the execution of the query. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "error" and "success". Is an "error" based on the query not returning a certain record? A certain number of records? Or do you want to catch SQL syntax/logic errors?

Comment: @Clive.. want to catch SQL syntax/logic errors

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow below code..

```
   try {
        $query = db_select('node', 'n');
        $query->fields('n', array('nid'));
        $nid = $query->execute()->fetchField();
        drupal_set_message(t('Print your sucess message here'));
      }
    catch(Exception $e){
        drupal_set_message(t('Print your error message here'),'error');
    }
```

Comment: Please stop signing your answers off with “Thank you”, it’s not necessary. Er, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can display drupal messages using the pre-defined function [drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7.x).

**For example:**

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$nid = $query->fields('n', array('nid'));
$nid = $nid->execute()->fetchField();
if(!empty($nid)){
     //Do something
     drupal_set_message(t('Your success message'), $type = 'status');
}else{
    //Do something
     drupal_set_message(t('Your error message'), $type = 'error');
}
```

For more information about messages, [click here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7.x)

Comment: @usmanjutt84..Thank you.. I updated the question now

Comment: @blue-moon, see I hope it'll helps